# Validate TextFormField in Flutter - What's wrong with this Regex?

Tags: regex, flutter, validation, dart, textformfield

I need to check a `TextFormField` to ensure the user only inputs alphanumeric characters with no spaces or other symbols.

I'm using `The Validator` plugin for flutter to validate my `TextFormField`.

I've created a controller;

```
               var _tag1Controller = TextEditingController();
```

and a Regex validator;

```
               TextFormField(
                          controller: _tag1Controller,
                          validator: FieldValidator.regExp(RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]\$'),'No hash/space'),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter Tag 1',                        
                          ),
                            onChanged: (tag1text) {
                            setState(() {
                              this.tag1 = tag1text;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

If the user inputs a hashtag or whitespace a message comes up which says 'No hash/space'.

But instead, the 'No hash/space'    message comes up no matter what the user inputs - even if it's clean with no symbols or spaces.

Can anyone see what's wrong with my Regex?

Comment: Yoy need to escape \. The easiest is to specify your `String` as raw string by putting an `r` before like: `r'^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]\$'`. It will then ignore the special meaning of \ and will just see \ as \.

Comment: You might try `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$`

Comment: The combination of the two worked! r'^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$'  If one of you wants to put it as the answer I'll choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match 1 or more characters, you have to repeat the character class one or more times using `+` or else it will match a single character.

If you want to assert the end of the string, you can use `$` without escaping.

Note that you don't have to escape the `-` in this case, but often this is either put at the start or at the end to prevent accidentally use it as a range.

```
r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$'
```

Comment: This needs the r suggested by julemand101  in the comments. Can you please edit to read r'^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$'  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use raw string literals, do not escape `$` in the end of string meaning and keep `-` to the edge of character classes.

Also, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w`.

Use

```
validator: FieldValidator.regExp(RegExp(r'^[\w-]$'),'No hash/space'),
```